# Why does Album Cover Art Downloader (Linux) not find any album cover art?

Tags: linux, mp3

I installed the Ablum cover Art Downloader on my OpenSuse11.4 laptop, but no matter how simple I make the search terms, the program does not find a thing.

I already tried all combinations of retrieval settings without luck.

And yes, my box is online.

Any hints where to look for the error?

Comment: Hi Viad, thanks for your hint! How can i migrate the question? Or should i simply repost it there?

Comment: It will be migrated automatically once at least five people vote to migrate it (see that "close" label with count?). Just make sure you follow the link once it has migrated to check out answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have a firewall or proxy blocking anything?
Although your box bay be online, sometimes extra ports need to be opened, or the proxy settings have to be manually configured within programs.